# How to execute Laravel nested query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have following 3 tables

**Classrooms**

`id  subject`

**RegisteredStudents**

`id  user_id  class_id`

**Posts**

`id  class_id  type attachment`

**Models**

*Classroom.php*

```
public function posts()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

*RegisteredStudents.php*

```
public function classroom()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Classroom::class);
}
```

*Post.php*

```
public function classroom()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Classroom::class);
}
```

Now I need to get all the posts of particular class, under which a student is registered.

for example, a student is registered for class which id no is 1 in classroom table. so it will be noted on registered_students table that this particular user is registered under this particular class. Every class may have multiple posts in post table. And the user need to get all post of his  class.

I'm trying something like this:

```
 $registered_classes = RegisteredStudent::where('user_id',$user->id)
            ->where(function ($q) use ($class_id){
                Post::where('class_id',$class_id);
            })->get();
```

which is definitely not correct. what will be the correct query for this.

Answer (score 2):

You have created `RegisteredStudent` model, with `classroom` relation. The problem is, if your `foreign_key` is different with Laravel Behavior, you have to include it in the relation. Like this:

**Classroom.php**

```
public function posts(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'class_id');
}
```

*Laravel Behavior need you to use `classroom_id` instead of `class_id`

**RegisteredStudent.php**

```
public function classroom(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Classroom::class, 'class_id');
}

public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Post.php**

```
public function classroom(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Classroom::class, 'class_id');
}
```

More detailed about how Laravel Behavior with full examples [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

***Edited**

Then, if you want to get All Posts of a particular Class under which a student is registered, you could use `with` method:

```
public function getAllPostsClassroom()
{
    $registeredUser = RegisteredStudent::where('user_id', $user->id)->with(['classroom.posts' => function($query) use ($class_id) {
        $query->where('class_id', $class_id);
    }])->first();
}
```

And you will get All `Posts` inside the `Classroom` of a Registered User

Comment: that does not FULLY answer the question. He is primarily asking for the correct query

Comment: what will be query ?

Comment: @OsmanRafi Edited. Plz lemme know if it's work.

Comment: this query does not return Posts rather it returns a RegiateredStudent instance

Comment: @Psycho of course, but you still get All `Posts` inside the `Classroom` of A Registered Student. I just following how @OsmanRafi start to use it. We could get All Post of a particular Classroom of a Registered Student from `Post`, `Classroom` of even `User` class

Comment: Undefined variable: class_id @TheArKa

Comment: They should have a `hasManyThrough` relationship set up from `User` to `Classroom`. `RegisteredStudent` is just a pivot model and shouldn't really be involved in the query directly.

Comment: @Thestranger right, I don't even know from where that $class_id come from, since @The stranger querying with that variable for getting specific `Classroom` not all, and I just wrap it in a function. Still my bad..

Answer (score 2):

You first need to correct the relationships as `TheArKa` said in his answer (as the table and class names are not properly following the laravel eloquent convention).

***Classroom.php***

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'class_id');
}
```

***RegisteredStudent.php***

```
public function classroom()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Classroom::class, 'class_id');
}
```

Then the correct query should be:

```php
$posts_of_class_of_user =
RegisteredStudent::where('user_id',$user->id)->first()->classroom->posts;
```

This will first get the registered user from RegisteredStudent and then it will get the Classroom instance from belongsTo relatation and then it will get the all the related `posts` from hasMany relation.

Note that using relation, you can avoid complex queries specially in your case. You don't need any complex query. Just use the eloquent relational approach.

Comment: It's throwing "Property [classroom] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance."

Comment: opps, just a `->first()` missing before classroom. updating my answer now

Comment: RegisteredStudent doesn't have a direct relationship with Post. so `->posts` supposed to throw an error. This could work if you make an 'hasManyThrough` relationship in the model. @Psycho

Comment: what you are talking about is accessing posts directly without classroom `RegisteredStudent::where('user_id',$user->id)->first()->posts` which is done by hasManyThrough, but i'm accessing like `classroom->posts`